# Is "not worth to do" an acceptable alternative to "not worth doing"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Basically what the title says, nothing more to add.

I've encountered the former form on the Internet more than once, hence the question. Thanks!

Comment: "not worth to do" does not seem to be standard English to me - barring further context.  "X is not worth doing" is common and understood (in my part of the world - US)

Comment: No. _Worth_ cannot take an infinitive complement clause. It requires an embedded question (_worth what you paid for it_) or a gerund (_worth looking at_), or a quantified noun phrase (_worth twenty dollars_). And [that's not the only weird constraint it has](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, guys! I specifically meant sentences like:

"It's not worth bothering with this guy." 
vs
"It's not worth to bother with this guy."

Also, on another note, is the following an acceptable use of "worth it"?

"It's not worth it to bother with this guy."

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's OK. Or at least it's not so bad; the gerund is still preferred. The _it_ is a dummy introduced by extraposition; it's not really necessary because it precedes the important NP. But the construction _worth it_ seems to have become a semi-fixed phrase that helps introduce an infinitive complement, since the dummy _it_ can be parsed as part of the (_for...to_) complementizer, and that helps identify the construction.

Answer (score -1):

I only know: The book is worth reading. Up to now I haven't seen an infinitive construction. Maybe worth + to do is used by some people who are not so sure in grammar things. But the construction worth + gerund can be found in any dictionary.
This construction is parallel to German

Das Buch ist lesenswert. Derived from Das Buch ist des Lesens wert.
In English

The book is worth reading.

And we may assume that it was: The book is worth of reading.

So I think the construction worth + gerund is rather stable.

[See OALD worth no. 3](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/worth_1)

Answer (score -1):

Not normally, no. I would stick with 'not worth doing'.

Comment: Please consider expanding you answer to include some reasoning.